# Parsing JSON in Erlang

Tags: json, erlang

I have a piece of JSON string, which I want to parse in Erlang. It looks like:

```
({ id1 : ["str1", "str2", "str3"], id2 : ["str4", "str5"]})
```

I looked at mochijson2, and a couple of other JSON parsers, but I really could not figure out how to do it. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not true JSON.  The keys need to be quoted and there should be no brackets around it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I once used the [erlang-json-eep-parser](http://github.com/jchris/erlang-json-eep-parser/tree/master), and tried it on your data.

```
7> json_eep:json_to_term("({ id1 : [\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"], id2 : [\"str4\", \"str5\"]})").
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {error,{1,json_lex2,{illegal,"("}},1}
     in function  json_eep:json_to_term/1
```

Right, it doesn't like the parentheses.

```
8> json_eep:json_to_term("{ id1 : [\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"], id2 : [\"str4\", \"str5\"]}").
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {error,{1,json_lex2,{illegal,"i"}},1}
     in function  json_eep:json_to_term/1
```

And it doesn't like the unquoted keys:

```
18> json_eep:json_to_term("{ \"id1\" : [\"str1\", \"str2\", \"str3\"], \"id2\" : [\"str4\", \"str5\"]}").
{[{<<"id1">>,[<<"str1">>,<<"str2">>,<<"str3">>]},
  {<<"id2">>,[<<"str4">>,<<"str5">>]}]}
```

That looks better.

So it seems that your data is *almost* JSON, at least as far as this parser is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

you can work on your JSON at the JSONLint validator:  http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your input is not quite JSON -- the keys need to be quoted, like this:

```
{ "id1" : ["str1", "str2", "str3"], "id2" : ["str4", "str5"]}
```

A good Erlang library for manipulating JSON is [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.json.org/ ?

or download "json4erlang" from here: [json-and-json-rpc-for-erlang](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2007/02/17/json-and-json-rpc-for-erlang)

Comment: Sorry I see the erlang-json-parser is "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Comment: Yes, I saw the RFC4627 implementation, but when I pass the above string as input to the decode() function, I am getting a "badarg" error...

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON keys are not valid according to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt. Once you correct it, there are plenty of JSON libraries for Erlang, my favorite is JSX(https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx/):

```
MyJSON = { "id1" : ["str1", "str2", "str3"], "id2" : ["str4", "str5"]},
jsx:decode(MyJSON, [return_maps]).
```

And it will return an Erlang map data structure that can be manipulated to your needs http://learnyousomeerlang.com/maps