# What is the most mature JSON library for Erlang?

Tags: json, erlang

I wanted to use YAML but there is not a single mature YAML library for Erlang. I know there are a few JSON libraries, but was wondering which is the most mature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069547/parsing-json-in-erlang)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the one from mochiweb: [mochijson.erl](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochijson.erl)

```
1> mochijson:decode("{\"Name\":\"Tom\",\"Age\":10}").   
{struct,[{"Name","Tom"},{"Age",10}]}
```

Comment: Cool, taking a look now. Is this your preferred choice?

Comment: Or mochijson2. Depends on your taste. The suggested one returns a record with strings; the '2' one returns no record and binaries.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer [Jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy). It works with binary and is realy fast.

```
1> jiffy:decode(<<"{\"Name\":\"Tom\",\"Age\":10}">>).
{[{<<"Name">>,<<"Tom">>},{<<"Age">>,10}]}
```

Can encode as well:

```
2> jiffy:encode({[{<<"Name">>,<<"Tom">>},{<<"Age">>,10}]}).
<<"{\"Name\":\"Tom\",\"Age\":10}">>
```

Answer (score 4):

Also check out [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx). "An erlang application for consuming, producing and manipulating json. Inspired by Yajl." I haven't tried it myself yet, but it looks promising.

As a side note; I found this library through [Jesse](https://github.com/klarna/jesse), a json schema validator by [Klarna](https://klarna.com/sv).

Answer (score 3):

I use the [json library](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/0244e95634e690a98bbd1a422c0ced9d6bd6159a/src/json2.erl) provided by yaws.

**Edit**: I actually switched over to Jiffy, see Konstantin's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Trapexit](http://projects.trapexit.org/web/) offers a really cool search feature for Erlang projects.

Lookup for JSON there, you'll find almost 13 results. Check the dates of the latest revisions, the user rating, the project activity status.

**UPDATE:** I've just found a similar question n [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069547/parsing-json-in-erlang/1069817#1069817).  Apparently, they are quite happy with the [erlang-json-eep-parser](http://github.com/jchris/erlang-json-eep-parser/tree/master) parser.

Comment: Yes, I looked here. which is your favorite?

Answer (score 2):

My favourite is mochijson2. The API is straightforward, it's fast enough for me (I never actually bothered to benchmark it though, to be honest--I'm mostly en- and de-coding small packets), and I've been using it in a stable "production server" for a year now or so. Just remember to install mochinum as well, mochijson2 uses it to encode large numbers, if you miss it, and you'll try to encode a large number, it will throw an exception.

See also: [mochijson2 examples (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000046/mochijson2-examples)