# Erlang keep string notation

Tags: string, erlang

I have the following:

```
Body = "{\"auth\": {\"tName\": \"str1\", \"passwordCredentials\": {\"username\": \"u\", \"password\": \"p\"}}}"
```

The data I use can't be hardcoded; I need to build `Body` based on the variables `TName = "str1"`, `UName="u"`, and `Password="p"`:

I tried:

```
Body = "{\"auth\": {\"tName\": TName, \"passwordCredentials\": {\"username\": UName, \"password\": Password}}}"
```

But with this approach `Body` was not constructed properly. How can I use variables to build it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang doesn't have any kind of [string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). You can do

```
Body = "{\"auth\": {\"tName\": " ++ TName ++ ", \"passwordCredentials\": {\"username\": " ++ UName ++ ", \"password\": " ++ Password ++ "}}}"
```

or

```
Body = lists:append(["{\"auth\": {\"tName\": ", TName, ", \"passwordCredentials\": {\"username\": ", UName, ", \"password\": ", Password, "}}}"])
```

(Change in the obvious way if you need to add quotes around `TName` and the rest.)

Much better, instead of constructing a string like this (do you really want to deal with all the `\"`, counting closing braces, etc.?), write a simple function which would take an Erlang term like `[{auth, [{tName, TName}, {passwordCredentials, [{userName, UName}, {password, Password}]]]` and builds the JSON string from it (I recommend using [binaries](http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) instead of strings for `TName` etc., since Erlang strings are just lists of numbers, and you may want to have lists of numbers in your term which aren't strings). Or use an existing JSON library (see [What is the most mature JSON library for Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395992/what-is-the-most-mature-json-library-for-erlang) for some suggestions), especially if you don't just need to build JSON but parse it as well.

Comment: You mean the second version? I've missed one of `++` there, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For making JSON I would definitely use some JSON library:

```
body(TName, UName, Password) ->
    jiffy:encode({
      [{<<"auth">>, {
            [{<<"tname">>, iolist_to_binary(TName)},
             {<<"passwordCredentials">>, {
                  [{<<"username">>, iolist_to_binary(UName)},
                   {<<"password">>, iolist_to_binary(Password)}]
                 }}]
           }}]
     }).
```