# Erlang: Parse string to json

Tags: json, string, erlang

I have the following string:

```
"{\"headers\":[\"CNPJ\",\"PDF\",\"error\"],\"rows\":[[\"17192451000170\",\"FILE:application/pdf;170286;\",null],[\"234566767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null],[\"233456767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null]]}"
```

how do I parse it to a normal Json format?

meaning:

```
{"rows" :[
 {"CNPJ":"17192451000170","PDF":"FILE:application/pdf;170286;","error":null},
 {"CNPJ":"17192451000170","PDF":"FILE:application/pdf;170286;","error":null},
 {"CNPJ":"17192451000170", "PDF":"FILE:application/pdf;170286;,"error":null"}
]}
```

or any other json format

Comment: Does your string *genuinely* have all those backslashes in, or is that what you're seeing in the debugger?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395992/what-is-the-most-mature-json-library-for-erlang?lq=1), though the answers don't mention how to parse JSON into Erlang maps, which is what I presume you want to do given the expected output in your question.

Comment: yes, my string genuinely has all those backslashes (it's not the debugger)

Comment: for example with using  [link jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) jsx:encode(<<your string>>).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a valid JSON format.

If you just want to strip `\` then you can simply:

```
(hbd@crayon2.yoonka.com)31> JsonOrg = <<"{\"headers\":[\"CNPJ\",\"PDF\",\"error\"],\"rows\":[[\"17192451000170\",\"FILE:application/pdf;170286;\",null],[\"234566767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null],[\"233456767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null]]}">>.
<<"{\"headers\":[\"CNPJ\",\"PDF\",\"error\"],\"rows\":[[\"17192451000170\",\"FILE:application/pdf;170286;\",null],[\"234566767544\",\"FI"...>>

(hbd@crayon2.yoonka.com)32> io:format("~s~n", [binary_to_list(JsonOrg)]).
{"headers":["CNPJ","PDF","error"],"rows":[["17192451000170","FILE:application/pdf;170286;",null],["234566767544","FILE:application/pdf;456378;",null],["233456767544","FILE:application/pdf;456378;",null]]}
ok
```

You can also parse back and forth between Json and Erlang. I tested that with the [yajler decoder](https://github.com/yoonka/yajler/blob/master/src/yajler.erl):

```
(hbd@crayon2.yoonka.com)43> {ok, Parsed} = yajler:decode(<<"{\"headers\":[\"CNPJ\",\"PDF\",\"error\"],\"rows\":[[\"17192451000170\",\"FILE:application/pdf;170286;\",null],[\"234566767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null],[\"233456767544\",\"FILE:application/pdf;456378;\",null]]}">>).
{ok,[{<<"headers">>,[<<"CNPJ">>,<<"PDF">>,<<"error">>]},
     {<<"rows">>,
      [[<<"17192451000170">>,<<"FILE:application/pdf;170286;">>,
        undefined],
       [<<"234566767544">>,<<"FILE:application/pdf;456378;">>,
        undefined],
       [<<"233456767544">>,<<"FILE:application/pdf;456378;">>,
        undefined]]}]}

(hbd@crayon2.yoonka.com)44> Json = binary:list_to_bin(yajler:encode(Parsed)).
<<"{\"headers\":[\"CNPJ\",\"PDF\",\"error\"],\"rows\":[[\"17192451000170\",\"FILE:application/pdf;170286;\",\"undefined\"],[\"2345667675"...>>
```

Yajler is an [Erlang NIF](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) so it is using a C library, in this case called [`yajl`](https://lloyd.github.io/yajl/), to do the actual parsing, but I imagine a similar result you would get from other Erlang applications that can parse JSON.

Comment: here is the inverse problem: get json from string, but not vice versa. So you need to use the encode function.